# How to determine meaning of ras-mc-ctl error messages?

Tags: 18.04, error-handling, cache, logs

`ras-mc-ctl --errors` is reporting results like:

> 661 2019-08-20 08:42:29 -0400 error: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region) Generic CACHE Level-3 Generic Error, mcg mcgstatus=0, mci Corrected_error Threshold based error status: yellow, mcgcap=0x00000c09, status=0x8c400c400001110b, addr=0x3334c0000080b06, misc=0x00b501c0, tsc=0x3c6571e2bbea4, walltime=0x5d5beab4, cpuid=0x000806e9, bank=0x00000008

and more frequently:

> 728 2019-08-31 13:35:59 -0400 error: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region) Generic CACHE Level-3 Generic Error, mcg mcgstatus=0, mci Corrected_error Threshold based error status: green, Large number of corrected cache errors. System operating, but might leadto uncorrected errors soon, mcgcap=0x00000c09, status=0x8c2000c00001110b, addr=0x2b6b100000374cf, misc=0x0001bdc0, tsc=0x376c4b0d8828, walltime=0x5d6aafff, cpuid=0x000806e9, bank=0x00000008

What do these messages actually mean, and what could/should one do about them?

### Additional info:

- This is an Intel NUC 7i7BNH, with 16 Gb memory, 500G SSD, and 4K monitor.
- It runs Ubuntu 18.0, with recent "apt upgrade".
- The BIOS was updated to the recent July version.
- I've made no hardware modifications.

`lshw -C memory` shows:

```
*-firmware                
    description: BIOS
    vendor: Intel Corp.
    physical id: 0
    version: BNKBL357.86A.0080.2019.0725.1139
    date: 07/25/2019
    size: 64KiB
    capacity: 8128KiB
    capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
*-memory
    description: System Memory
    physical id: 28
    slot: System board or motherboard
    size: 16GiB
    *-bank:0
        description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
        product: CMSO16GX4M1A2133C15
        vendor: AMI
        physical id: 0
        serial: 00000000
        slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        size: 16GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:1
        description: [empty]
        physical id: 1
        slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
*-cache:0
    description: L1 cache
    physical id: 2d
    slot: L1 Cache
    size: 128KiB
    capacity: 128KiB
    capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
    configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
    description: L2 cache
    physical id: 2e
    slot: L2 Cache
    size: 512KiB
    capacity: 512KiB
    capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
    configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
    description: L3 cache
    physical id: 2f
    slot: L3 Cache
    size: 4MiB
    capacity: 4MiB
    capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
    configuration: level=3
*-memory UNCLAIMED
    description: Memory controller
    product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1f.2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
    version: 21
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
    capabilities: bus_master
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:dc244000-dc247fff
```

### Test results:

Running memtest86 produced some interesting results:

- After about 5 minutes, it displayed the Intel logo and rebooted.
- The same thing happened again, but I managed to record most of the messages first.
- The third time, it completed a full pass (about 45 minutes), and then crashed again a few minutes into the second pass.
- I'll leave it running, but I doubt it will make it through 4 passes.

The second attempt resulted in:

```
Test 4: Addr: 33090D380 Expected 08080808 Actual: 18080808 CPU:2
Test 4: Addr: 33090D38C Expected 08080808 Actual: 08080818 CPU:2
Test 4: Addr: 33090D390 Expected 08080808 Actual: [???]
Test 4: Addr: 33090D394 Expected 08080808 Actual: [???]
```

The third time, which made it through the first pass, showed:

[image: screenshot]

Note that the addresses aren't the same as the previous time (though both had 4 errors).

Comment: Have you overclocked your CPU or enabled memory XMP?

Comment: @heynnema, I've made no modifications.  See added details in question.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete. Report back.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema, or I'll surely miss them. Esp when you add requested info to your question.

Comment: @heynnema, sorry, I added the lshw results, but didn't want to bother you until I had the memtest86 results too.  Pass #1 is there now.  If it's possible to get all four, I'll add them.

Comment: Please see my answer. It's clearly defective hardware. Is your CPU overclocked, or memory XMP enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Did you come up with a final solution?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema, I agree, it's defective hardware.

Comment: Have you determined which one, or is that pending? Do you have another RAM stick to try? Is your CPU overclocked, or memory XMP enabled? Inquiring minds would like to know :-)

Comment: @heynnema, as I said yesterday, I've made no modifications (e.g. overclocking).  I did increase the memory a few months ago and had occasional random crashes before that, so I suspect it's not the memory card.  I'm getting more frequent crashes now, which is why I started looking at the logs.  Today is the middle of a long weekend here, but I'll likely take it to a repair shop on Tuesday.  Knowing that it crashes with memtest86 makes it obvious that the problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu software.

Comment: Then it's probably the cache memory on the motherboard. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

`memtest` failed.

You've either got a defective 16G RAM stick, or bad cache memory on your motherboard. Try re-seating the 16G RAM stick and see if it helps. FYI: for optimum memory speed, it's better to have two 8G RAM sticks instead of one 16G RAM stick. It also makes it easier to troubleshoot memory issues.

Check to make sure that your CPU is not overclocked, or that memory XMP is not enabled in your BIOS.

Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS.

**Update #1:**

User has the latest BIOS, version: BNKBL357.86A.0080.2019.0725.1139,
    date: 07/25/2019